# Programming a basic conditional method in ruby

Tags: ruby

Create a mothod that takes two arguments.. The first argument represents what the user wants to buy (either a "computer" or "iPad").
The second argument represents how much money the user has. The method should evaluate if the user has enough money to buy a computer or an iPad. If the user has enough money for a computer or an iPad, the method should return true, otherwise it should return false.

This is what I have so far, but it's not returning right whenever I run it with sample arguments.

```
def can_i_get?(item,money)
  if item=="computer" 
    if money >= 1000
      return true
    end

  elsif item=="iPad"
    if money >= 500
      return true
    end

  else
    return false
  end

end
```

Comment: Your program will only return "false" when the item is not "computer" or "iPad", there are no conditionals to return "false" when there's not enough money - in that case it would just return `nil`, that's what you need to fix.

Comment: You could replace the body of the method with the following line:  `(item=="computer"  && money >= 1000) || (item=="iPad" && money >= 500)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the method body with this condition:

```
def can_i_get?(item, money)
  item == 'computer' && money >= 1000 || item == 'iPad' && money >= 500
end
```

No need for `if ... elsif ... else` or a `return`.

Answer (score 3):

What if `item` is `computer` and `money` is less than `500`? There's nothing to catch conditions like this, so the method returns `nil`.

Instead, make the `return false` a catch-all:

```
def can_i_get?(item,money)
  if item=="computer" 
    if money >= 1000
      return true
    end
  elsif item=="iPad"
    if money >= 500
      return true
    end
  end
  return false
end
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use `return` in Ruby, as the method automatically returns the last item evaluated.

I would define your items and costs in a Hash and reference that from within your method:

```
PRICE_LIST = {'computer' => 1000, 'iPad' => 500}

def can_i_get?(item, money)
  money >= PRICE_LIST.fetch(item, Float::INFINITY)
end
```

This is both readable and extensible--you can add items and costs to PRICE_LIST and the method will work for the new items.

By using [`Hash#fetch`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Hash.html#method-i-fetch), we get back the default value (the second argument) if the item is not found within the PRICE_LIST. Returning `Float::INFINITY` ensures that an unknown item will evaluate to `false`.

Comment: I like this version, but may I suggest handling the case in which the `item` is not in the list. Perhaps with `PRICE_LIST.fetch(item, 0)`?

Comment: @spickermann you meant `PRICE_LIST.fetch[item, Float::INFINITY]`?

Comment: @mudasobwa You are right, that makes more sense in this context.

Comment: @spickermann we cannot decide whether the user has enough money if we don't know the item's price. An exception seems appropriate in this case.

Comment: @Stefan The example provided by the OP indicates that `false` is the correct response for unknown items.

Answer (score 0):

I like Yu Hao's answer because it solves the `nil` problem you may be having. I would just add that you could also use a dictionary for efficiency, in case you want to add more items to check in the future, and remove some duplicate code.

```
def can_i_get?(item,money)

  item_cost = {
    "computer" => 1000,
    "iPad" => 500
  }

  item_cost.key?(item) && money >= item_cost[item]
end
```